# What is the easiest way to find whether a particular LocalDate falls within a YearMonth?

Tags: java, java-time, date-comparison, localdate

The [documentation for `YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) does not have any advice for how to handle this.

At the moment I'm using the following method to check whether a `LocalDate` falls within a `YearMonth`, where `date` and `yearMonth` are values for those respectively:

```
YearMonth lastDayOfPreviousMonth = yearMonth.atDay(1).minusDay(1);
YearMonth firstDayOfNextMonth = yearMonth.atEndOfMonth().plusDays(1);
return date.isAfter(lastDayOfPreviousMonth)
                && date.isBefore(firstDayOfNextMonth);
```

Is there any cleaner or in-built way to do this?

Comment: Why can't you simply compare the month value?

Comment: Because I wasn't thinking outside the box? That's probably a clearer way to do this: although, I'd have to compare the month and year value!

Comment: Which has lead me to think that `YearMonth.from(date).equals(yearMonth)` is probably the easiest way to do it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by @cricket_007 in the question's comments, a cleaner way to check whether a `LocalDate` falls within the `YearMonth` is to get the `YearMonth` of the `date` and then to compare that to the original to the `yearMonth`:

```
return YearMonth.from(date).equals(yearMonth);
```

Answer (score 0):

More direct way

```
fun LocalDate.toYearMonth(): YearMonth {
    return YearMonth.of(get(ChronoField.YEAR), get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR))
}
```